# DataTable in ViewState is Returning Deleted Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, viewstate

I am currently working on a dynamic gridview that will allow a user to add or delete rows in order to be saved as database entries later on.

My gridview markup is as such:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAirporterSchedule" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvAirporterSchedule" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" OnRowDataBound="gvAirporterSchedule_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvAirporterSchedule_RowCommand">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location" ItemStyle-Width="25%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlScheduleLoc" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAirporterStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control date-picker" Text='<%# Eval("StartDateColumn") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="End Date">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAirporterEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control date-picker" Text='<%# Eval("EndDateColumn") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Departure Time">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAirporterDepTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control time-picker" Text='<%# Eval("DeptTimeColumn") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxAirporterDuration" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("DurationColumn") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Delete" CommandName="DeleteRow" />
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Add Entry" CommandName="AddRow" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Aside from this grid, I have some other fields in the user control. When I go to save, the user will click a button at the bottom of the user control which will package up the form fields above it and the grid into some classes and shoot this off to the database code to add/update this data.

```
Page.Validate("AirporterFares");

        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // Save trip information.
                SysVarService.SharedRideTrip trip = new SysVarService.SharedRideTrip();

                if (_tripID > 0)
                    trip = Global.sysVarService.GetSharedRideTripByID(_tripID);

                trip.isVisible = 1;
                trip.productType = ReservationService.ProductType.TOUR;
                trip.originStopID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlOrigin.SelectedValue.ToString());
                trip.destinationStopID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlDestination.SelectedValue.ToString());
                trip.defaultDuration = 0;
                trip.effectiveDate = DateTime.Parse(tbxAirporterEffDate.Text.Trim());
                trip.startTimeOfDay = new DateTime(trip.effectiveDate.Year, trip.effectiveDate.Month, trip.effectiveDate.Day, 1, 1, 1);
                trip.endTimeOfDay = new DateTime(trip.effectiveDate.Year, trip.effectiveDate.Month, trip.effectiveDate.Day, 1, 1, 1);

                // Save the two fare information.
                SysVarService.SharedRideTrip_ShuttleFare aFare = new SysVarService.SharedRideTrip_ShuttleFare()
                {
                    effectiveDate = trip.effectiveDate,
                    effectiveTravelDate = trip.effectiveDate,
                    paxTypeID = 1,
                    oneWayCost = Foundation.StringFormatter.currencyToDouble(tbxAirporterAdultFare.Text.Trim()),
                    returnCost = 0.00,
                    numPax = 1,
                    Currency = 0
                };

                SysVarService.SharedRideTrip_ShuttleFare cFare = new SysVarService.SharedRideTrip_ShuttleFare()
                {
                    effectiveDate = trip.effectiveDate,
                    effectiveTravelDate = trip.effectiveDate,
                    paxTypeID = 2,
                    oneWayCost = Foundation.StringFormatter.currencyToDouble(tbxAirporterChildFare.Text.Trim()),
                    returnCost = 0.00,
                    numPax = 1,
                    Currency = 0
                };

                string status = "";

                if (_updating)
                    status = Global.sysVarService.UpdateAirporterFare(trip, aFare, cFare, GetScheduleEntries());
                else
                    status = Global.sysVarService.AddAirporterFare(trip, aFare, cFare, GetScheduleEntries());

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
                {
                    spanErrorMsg.Visible = true;
                    spanErrorMsg.InnerText = status;
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                spanErrorMsg.Visible = true;
                spanErrorMsg.InnerText = ex.ToString();
                return;
            }

            Response.Redirect("~/Internal/Admin/Default.aspx?action=Airporter_Fares");
        }
```

When I go to either add or update, I call GetScheduledEntries, which is supposed to loop through the datatable (grabbing it from the viewstate) and convert the templated fields into object properties and stuff these objects in a list.

```
private List<AdminConfigService.SharedRideTimes> GetScheduleEntries()
{
    int idx = 0;

    List<AdminConfigService.SharedRideTimes> schedule = new List<AdminConfigService.SharedRideTimes>();

    if (gvAirporterSchedule.Rows.Count >= 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= gvAirporterSchedule.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            // Get data controls.
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlScheduleLoc");

            TextBox startDate = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[1].FindControl("tbxAirporterStartDate");
            TextBox endDate = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[2].FindControl("tbxAirporterEndDate");
            TextBox deptTime = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[3].FindControl("tbxAirporterDepTime");
            TextBox duration = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[4].FindControl("tbxAirporterDuration");

            schedule.Add(new AdminConfigService.SharedRideTimes()
            {
                StartDate = DateTime.Parse(startDate.Text.Trim()),
                EndDate = DateTime.Parse(endDate.Text.Trim()),
                DepartureTime = DateTime.Parse(deptTime.Text.Trim()),
                Duration = Convert.ToInt32(duration.Text.Trim()),
                EffectiveDates = "",
                StopID = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue.ToString())
            });

            idx++;
        }

        return schedule;
    }
    else
        return schedule;
}
```

The problem is, if I delete rows from this grid view and then attempt to save the form, the datatable from the viewstate is bringing back those deleted rows and acting like they are still existing for saving, even though the gridview and the datatable do not have that row anymore (when the DeleteRow command goes through).

```
else if (e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
    {
        SetRowData();

        if (ViewState["AirporterScheduleTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["AirporterScheduleTable"];
            DataRow currentRow = null;

            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int idx = gvr.RowIndex;

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[idx]);
                currentRow = dt.NewRow();

                ViewState["AirporterScheduleTable"] = dt;

                gvAirporterSchedule.DataSource = dt;
                gvAirporterSchedule.DataBind();

                SetPreviousData();
            }
        }
    }

private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int idx = 0;

    if (ViewState["AirporterScheduleTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["AirporterScheduleTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                // Get data controls.
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlScheduleLoc");

                TextBox startDate = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[1].FindControl("tbxAirporterStartDate");
                TextBox endDate = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[2].FindControl("tbxAirporterEndDate");
                TextBox deptTime = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[3].FindControl("tbxAirporterDepTime");
                TextBox duration = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[4].FindControl("tbxAirporterDuration");

                ddl.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[i]["LocColumn"].ToString();
                startDate.Text = dt.Rows[i]["StartDateColumn"].ToString();
                endDate.Text = dt.Rows[i]["EndDateColumn"].ToString();
                deptTime.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DeptTimeColumn"].ToString();
                duration.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DurationColumn"].ToString();

                idx++;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void SetRowData()
{
    int idx = 0;

    if (ViewState["AirporterScheduleTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable current = (DataTable)ViewState["AirporterScheduleTable"];
        DataRow currentRow = null;

        if (current.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= current.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                // Get data controls.
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlScheduleLoc");

                TextBox startDate = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[1].FindControl("tbxAirporterStartDate");
                TextBox endDate = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[2].FindControl("tbxAirporterEndDate");
                TextBox deptTime = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[3].FindControl("tbxAirporterDepTime");
                TextBox duration = (TextBox)gvAirporterSchedule.Rows[idx].Cells[4].FindControl("tbxAirporterDuration");

                currentRow = current.NewRow();

                current.Rows[i - 1]["LocColumn"] = ddl.SelectedValue;
                current.Rows[i - 1]["StartDateColumn"] = startDate.Text;
                current.Rows[i - 1]["EndDateColumn"] = endDate.Text;
                current.Rows[i - 1]["DeptTimeColumn"] = deptTime.Text;
                current.Rows[i - 1]["DurationColumn"] = duration.Text;

                idx++;
            }

            ViewState["AirporterScheduleTable"] = current;
        }
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any where in the code that I am not updating the ViewState datatable when I either delete or add entries to this dynamic gridview. What could be causing the difference in ViewStates? Does the full postback of the button outside of the UpdatePanel and GridView have a different ViewState?

I also pretty much followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET) exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be one of those cases where you overlook something simple. When I was populating the grid with data on load, I did not protect it with a

```
if (!Page.IsPostback)
```

Because of that, every time the row was deleted, it would refill the data table with the data on Page Load and cause the weird issues where deleted rows didn't seem to be getting deleted.